# Unrecognized escape sequence in C#, translating from vb.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm attempting to translate a vb function into a c# method. What would the below expression be in C#?

"<\$date\$>"

This causes an unrecognized escape sequence when pasted into a C# project

Comment: What does the original VB code look like?

Answer (score 6):

put a `@` in front of your string. `@"<\$date\$>"`

> A verbatim string literal consists of an @ character followed by a double-quote character, zero or more characters, and a closing double-quote character. A simple example is @"hello". In a verbatim string literal, the characters between the delimiters are interpreted verbatim, the only exception being a quote-escape-sequence. In particular, simple escape sequences and hexadecimal and Unicode escape sequences are not processed in verbatim string literals. A verbatim string literal may span multiple lines.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: +1 @sean the \ has a special meaning in C# strings. Use @ to avoid the special treatment for \